# Try to login users in wordpress from moodle

Tags: wordpress, moodle, wordpress-plugin-creation

In moodle plugin I added this functions which use curl request to login user from moodle into wordpress

```
public function login_logout_user_to_wordpress($userid, $method) {
    $allowed = get_config('enrol_wallet', 'wordpressloggins');
    if (!$allowed) {
        return false;
    }
    $data = [
        'moodle_user_id' => $userid,
        'method' => $method,
        'url' => $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']];
    $response = $this->request('login_logout', $data);
    if ($response) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $this->create_wordpress_user($userid);
        return $this->request('login_logout', $data);
    }
}
```

And,

```
public function request($method, $data) {

    $wordpressurl = get_config('enrol_wallet', 'wordpress_url');
    if (empty($wordpressurl)) {
        return;
    }
    $url = $wordpressurl . self::ENDPOINT . $method;
    $encrypted = $this->encrypt_data($data);
    $sendingdata = [
        'encdata' => $encrypted,
    ];
    $curl = curl_init();
    $curlsetopt = [
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => ($method == 'login_logout') ? false : true,

    ];
    if ($method !== 'login_logout') {
        $curlsetopt[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = json_encode($sendingdata);
        $curlsetopt[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = array('Content-Type: application/json');
    } else {
        // I need to send the data here using get method.
        $curlsetopt[CURLOPT_URL] = $url.'?'.http_build_query($sendingdata);
        $curlsetopt[CURLOPT_HTTPGET] = true;
    }
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $curlsetopt);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($curl);

    if ($httpcode != 200) {
        // Endpoint returned an error.
        return get_string('endpoint_error', 'enrol_wallet');
    }
    if ($method !== 'login_logout') {
        return json_decode($response, true);
    }

    return json_decode($response, true);
}
```

And in wordpress:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('moo-wallet/v1', '/login_logout', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'moo_wallet_login_logout_user',
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
    ));
});

function moo_wallet_login_logout_user($request) {
    error_log('login-logout function called.'."\n", 3, __DIR__.'\debug.log');
    $encdata = $request->get_param('encdata');
    $data = moo_wallet_decrypt_data($encdata);
    if (empty($data)) {
        return 'Key not match';
    }
    $moodleid = $data['moodle_user_id'];
    $method = $data['method'];
    $url = $data['url'];
    $wordpress_user_id = moo_wallet_userid_by_moodleid($moodleid);
    if (!empty($wordpress_user_id)) {
        // Login the user.
        if ($method == 'login') {
            if (is_user_logged_in()) {
                error_log('user is logged in'."\n", 3, __DIR__.'\debug.log');
                wp_logout();
            }
            error_log('user not logged in'."\n", 3, __DIR__.'\debug.log');
            error_log('try to login user with id: '.$wordpress_user_id."\n", 3, __DIR__.'\debug.log');
            $user = get_userdata($wordpress_user_id);
            error_log('get_userdata called'."\n", 3, __DIR__.'\debug.log');
            if (!$user) {
                error_log('user not found'."\n", 3, __DIR__.'\debug.log');
                return false;
            }
            wp_clear_auth_cookie();
            wp_set_auth_cookie($wordpress_user_id, false, false);
            error_log('wp_set_auth_cookie called'."\n", 3, __DIR__.'\debug.log');
            wp_set_current_user($wordpress_user_id, $user->user_login);
            error_log('wp_set_current_user called'."\n", 3, __DIR__.'\debug.log');
            error_log('logged in'."\n", 3, __DIR__.'\debug.log');
            wp_redirect($url);
            return true;
        // Logout the user.
        } else if ($method == 'logout') {
            wp_logout();
            wp_clear_auth_cookie();
            error_log('logged out'."\n", 3, __DIR__.'\debug.log');
            wp_redirect($url);
            return true;
        // Invalid method.
        } else {
            error_log('ivalid method'."\n", 3, __DIR__.'\debug.log');
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        error_log('ivalid user'."\n", 3, __DIR__.'\debug.log');

        // User not found.
        return false;
    }
}
```

but for some reason it is not working
this is an example from the log data

```
login-logout function called.
user not logged in
try to login user with id: 2
get_userdata called
wp_set_auth_cookie called
wp_set_current_user called
logged in
```

I think that as the request is done from server side, that is why the user not set correctly neither the cookies.

Any help?